# Value of information in the Moral hazard in teams context

Tags: mathematical-economics, asymmetric-information, contract-theory

I have a few mathematical problems with the paper [Moral hazard in teams](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Moral-Hazard-in-Teams-Holmstrom/cba2bb5ba762a43495fdf5ec8cf64f1fd9839045) 1982 by Bengt Holmstrom, especially in chapter 3. (sufficient statistic) page 330 following

The welfare problem can be stated as:
$$
 \max\limits_{s_i(y) ,a} \int \left[ E(x \vert y,a) - \sum_{i}^{n}s_iy\right] dF(y,a),
$$
subjected to:
$$
\int u_i(s_i(y)) dF(y,a) -v_i(a_i)\geq 
\underline{u_i}, \qquad i=1{,}...,n,
$$
$$
 a_i \in arg \max\limits_{a^\prime_i} 
\int u_i(s_i(y))dF(y,a^\prime_i,a_{-i})-v_i(a^\prime_i), \qquad i=1{,}...,n.
$$
and the definition of a sufficient statistic $T_i(y)$ is given by:
$$
f(y,a) = h_i(y,a_{-i})p_i(T_i(y),a) \qquad \forall x,a. \qquad (1)
$$

I consider first the case of a single agent, dropping subscripts throughout. Define
$\tilde{s}(T)$  as follows:

$$
u( \tilde{s}(T))=\frac{\int_{T(y)=T}^{}  u(s(y))f(y,a) dy}{p(T,a)}  =\int_{}^{} u(s(y))h(y)dy \qquad (2)
$$
By Jensen inequality:
$$
\int \tilde{s}(T)f(y,a)dy\leq \int s(y)f(y,a)dy \qquad (3)
$$

Why follows from (1) and (2) that the agent will enjoy the same expected utility for all
$a$, whether faced with $s(y)$ or $\tilde{s}(T)$?
I understand that:$$
u( \tilde{s}(T))=\int_{T(y)=T}^{}  u(s(y))f(y,a) dy  =p(T,a) \int_{T(y)=T}^{} u(s(y))h(y)dy 
$$
but i don't know how to show that it is true.

Why follows from this and (3), that the principal is at least as well off
with $\tilde{s}(T)$ as with $s(y)$?

Why are we using the Stieltjes integral in the welfare problem but lebesque for the sharing rules?

And what does, $\{y \vert T(y)=T\}$ exactly mean. I know all $y$ for which $ T(y)$is equal $T$. But i dont get why we need that.

I am happy about any suggestions. Thanks a lot :)